# Suppress Orphaned Nested Group Headers

Tags: crystal-reports

I need a way to make sure a group header is not the last thing on the page without keeping the entire group together. The group is too large to keep together. All I want is to make sure the group header is not the last thing printed on a page.

```
Group Header A  
Group Header B  
Data 1  
Data 2  
Data 3  
Data 4  
GroupHeader A  
!PAGE BREAK  
GroupHeader B  
Data 5  
Data 6  
Data 7  
Data 8
```

Or

```
Group Header A  
Group Header B  
Data 1  
Data 2  
Data 3  
Data 4  
GroupHeader A  
GroupHeader B  
!PAGE BREAK  
Data 5  
Data 6  
Data 7  
Data 8
```

I need like this

```
Group Header A  
Group Header B  
Data 1  
Data 2  
Data 3  
Data 4   
!PAGE BREAK  
GroupHeader A  
GroupHeader B 
Data 5  
Data 6  
Data 7  
Data 8
```

Comment: Have a look at this [guide](https://www.microassist.com/software-tips/crystal-reports-prevent-an-orphaned-group-header/) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659584/suppress-group-header-when-no-record-below). Both show a way to prevent an orphaned header. Maybe you can adapt that to prevent GroupheaderA and B to be orphaned.

Comment: If GrroupHeader B is null (Suppress is blank) this 2 solutions are worked as well. But if GroupHeader B not blank it not working.

Comment: Can you clarify: Should GroupHeader A and B always be printed together? Do they belong to the same group?